# Detect if a tab was POSTed to from Google Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to detect if a particular tab was POSTed to via a Google Chrome extension? I am working on an extension that includes an "undo closed tab" type of function and would like to handle tabs which were POSTed to differently than GET pages.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a solution exists in [chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onBeforeRequest) via the 'method' return parameter. I will report back with a working code example once I have time to try this out.